# Confusion Regarding Default Constructor

Tags: c#, default-constructor

```
using System;
class Test
{
    string name;
    int num1, num2;

    public Test()
    {
        num1=10;
        num2=20;
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(num1+num2);
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

}

class TestDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Test ob = new Test();
        ob.Show();
    }
}
```

Confusion:

The Complete Reference C# 3.0 says that a default constructor will not be called if you define your own constructor. I did that thing, but left the string variable without initializing it with my defined constructor. Now according to above concept the string variable is not initialized and no default constructor will run to give it a default value because I have defined my own.

So, why it does not show an error, that string is not initialized with any value or something similar. Doesn't it show that it has been assigned a value from somewhere [default constructor of compiler]?

Comment: First, the "default constructor" would also not initialize your string either; it will be initialized to null automatically. Second, yes, your `name` variable will be null, so `Console.WriteLine(name)` won't write anything, but it won't blow up either.  If you did something like `Console.WriteLine(name.ToUpper())` then you'd get a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing as an "uninitialized" field (whether static or instance). *All* fields are initialized with a default value (null for reference types, the "natural zero" for value types).

The compiler will give you a warning if you include a `readonly` field which isn't assigned a value in the constructor, as then it will *always* have that default value - but it's still initalized.

The compiler can only spot when a *local* variable is used without being definitely assigned. That's because the compiler has a lot more information about control flow within a method than *between* methods within a class. If you have one method which assigns a value to a field and another which fetches the value from the field, there's no way for the compiler to know which will be called first - whereas the rules of definite assignment allow it to analyze a method to spot *potential* flows where a variable is read without having been assigned a value first.

None of this really has anything to do with default constructors, by the way. The compiler only *provides* a default constructor if you don't provide any constructors at all - so in your `Test` class, there's no *default* constructor as such, because you've provided your own parameterless constructor. Even if the compiler *did* provide a default constructor, it would be exactly equivalent to:

```
public Test() {}
```

... the fields would still just have their default values.

Comment: Sir, then y do we say that the constructor intializes the instance variables its default value...? i am still confused bro.

Comment: @Jon Skeet IMO you should edit your this line `All fields are initialized ` with `All INSTANCE fields are initialized`. As one might take that line for method local variables as well - where one need to initialize fields before using them.

Comment: @sansix Local variables aren't fields.

Comment: @RanjhaniSaddam: All fields are initialized to their default values on object creation, before the *constructors* run at all.

Comment: @sansix: What hvd said. I very carefully chose the word *fields* rather than *variables*.

Comment: @JonSkeet +1 yeah my bad - just verified it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx :P

Comment: Bro sansix and Jon Skeet:
if i am not wrong then you mean that we can have uninitialized local variables inside method, whose value must be given before use, or else compiler will generate error,
but its not the case with the fields of class, and there is no such thing like "uninitialized field".? declaration of fields will initialize them with their default value???

Comment: Thnx Buddy, You Solved My Big Misconception... :) Hats Off

Answer (score -1):

Your constructor

```
  public Test()
  {
      num1=10;
      num2=20;
  }
```

is same as

```
 public Test()
 {     
 }
```

If you want to initialize `num1` and `num2` , you can do it as below:

```
private int num1, num2; //public fields are not recommended

public Test(int numberOne, int numberTwo)
{
    num1 = numberOne;
    num2 = numberTwo;
}
```

and you can do initialization as below:

```
Test ob = new Test(10,20);
```